# ASP.NET Core and Database Connection Pooling

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, connection-pooling, kestrel-http-server

I am using ASP.NET Core with Dapper, probably on Kestrel with SQL Server reverse proxy. How is database connection pooling handling in this type of an architecture? Thanks!